# Getting average in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have this collection names bankdata, where I have this info

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("574462ffbb61fc35622bd1f3"), "first_name" : "GEORGE", "last_name" : "SMITH", "accounts" : [ { "account_type" : "Checking", "account_balance" : 7510049.716676093, "currency" : "PESO" }, { "account_type" : "Investment", "account_balance" : 8978088.436168617, "currency" : "USD" }, { "account_type" : "401K", "account_balance" : 3536582.866462197, "currency" : "YEN" }, { "account_type" : "Checking", "account_balance" : 4390095.46173461, "currency" : "USD" } ] }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("574462ffbb61fc35622bd1f4"), "first_name" : "STEVEN", "last_name" : "SMITH", "accounts" : [ { "account_type" : "Investment", "account_balance" : 7606194.17605087, "currency" : "EURO" }, { "account_type" : "Investment", "account_balance" : 2099711.775821766, "currency" : "EURO" }, { "account_type" : "Investment", "account_balance" : 2961011.973269031, "currency" : "YUAN" }, { "account_type" : "Savings", "account_balance" : 5830306.873168334, "currency" : "USD" }, { "account_type" : "401K", "account_balance" : 1542091.8696738125, "currency" : "EURO" } ] }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("574462ffbb61fc35622bd1f5"), "first_name" : "BRIAN", "last_name" : "SMITH", "accounts" : [ { "account_type" : "401K", "account_balance" : 149839.10500178766, "currency" : "PESO" } ] }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("574462ffbb61fc35622bd1f6"), "first_name" : "EDWARD", "last_name" : "SMITH", "accounts" : [ { "account_type" : "401K", "account_balance" : 6577381.434625924, "currency" : "YEN" }, { "account_type" : "Checking", "account_balance" : 8998935.759297138, "currency" : "USD" }, { "account_type" : "Investment", "account_balance" : 588000.4045217587, "currency" : "YUAN" }, { "account_type" : "Savings", "account_balance" : 6743563.754405159, "currency" : "YUAN" }, { "account_type" : "401K", "account_balance" : 8580650.627761671, "currency" : "POUNDS STERLING" }, { "account_type" : "401K", "account_balance" : 7687815.685781645, "currency" : "YEN" }, { "account_type" : "Checking", "account_balance" : 9128407.633252997, "currency" : "EURO" } ] }
```

I want to get the average Account balance for all the accounts with an account balance greater than 1,000,000.00.

I made this query, but I don't know how to get the average account balance.

```
db.bankdata.find({ accounts: { $elemMatch : {  'account_balance' : { $gt: 1000000 } } } }, { 'accounts.$' : 1, first_name: 1, last_name: 1} )
```

Answer (score 1):

you could get average by grouping like this. (i just created a dummy collection. you may have to modified the attribute names accordingly)

```
 db.bank.aggregate([{$unwind:"$accounts"},{$match:{"accounts.balance":{"$gt":35555}}},{$group:{_id:{name:"$firstname"},avgbalance:{$avg:"$accounts.balance"}}}])
```

But I would also reconsider based on Elyasin's inputs.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

has details on what the above command is using. 
First deconstruct the array for each element as you need to group on them.
and then add Match in pipleline to have balance greater than "a" value. 
and finally group on an element(I used firstname here) $avg is mongo command.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the *aggregate* framework. But to be honest, you should stop and think about what you want to do exactly.

I only had a quick glance at your question details, but it already struck me.

1. You might want to consider redesigning your model. Maybe `account_type` should be a reference to a document of account types? Maybe `accounts` should be references to account documents. You are putting all in one document, but to me it does not look right. You can do that if you want, but you definitely can do better.
2. Second and most important. MongoDB is not suitable for financial applications at all. This is because floating point numbers lose precision in the format MongoDB stores them; you have to read about Floating Points to understand the impact. The bottom line is that the floating points sometime cannot be stored with the exact value you want it to have. And when you sum up floating point values this will be noticeable and your results wrong.

I suggest you take a step back and consider what you want to achieve. If it is for learning purposes, well you just learned something.
Otherwise I recommend to use a database that can store decimal numbers without loss up to a precision you need/defined and that offers ACID constraints since you have to deal with transactions.